# AFNetworking parsing requestObject

Tags: objective-c, json, http, nsdictionary, afnetworking-2

I am not sure what is happening but it may be an issue with `AFJSONSerializer`. Currently I am retrieving JSON data from a URL that returns (in browser):

```
[{"id": 1, "email": "random@gmail.com", "password": "123"}, {"id": 2, "email": "david@gmail.com", "password": "123"}]
```

I then do a `GET` request with AFNetworking:

```
[manager GET:path
    parameters:nil
    success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
        user = [self parseJsonData:responseObject];
    }
    failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

The `responseObject` returned by the success block always returns:

```
({"id": 1, "email": "random@gmail.com", "password": "123"}, ...etc...)
```

Notice the regular braces instead of square braces. This causes the parse to NSDictionary or NSArray to fail. I can see the objects being returned but I cannot parse them to their respective types. In fact if I attempt the parse to NSDictionary it will show the correct number of objects, all being blank.

Clicking the inspector icon for each index provides me with this error:

```
[0] = <error: expected ']'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking has already parsed the JSON for you (because the `manager`'s default `responseSerializer` is `AFJSONResponseSerializer`). You're doing a `NSLog` of `responseObject`, which is a `NSArray` object, not of a JSON string. And when you log a `NSArray`, it uses the parentheses rather than the square brackets.

If you look at `[responseObject class]` or `[responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]`, you can confirm that `responseObject` is already been parsed into a `NSArray`, which you can now use directly.

---

For example, given that AFNetworking has already parsed the JSON for you, you can now use the resulting object:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = responseObject[0];    // get the first dictionary from the array

NSNumber *identifier = dictionary[@"id"];        // this will be @(1)
NSString *email      = dictionary[@"email"];     // this will be @"random@gmail.com"
NSString *password   = dictionary[@"password"];  // this will be @"123"
```

Or you can iterate through the array:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in responseObject) {
    NSNumber *identifier = dictionary[@"id"]; 
    NSString *email      = dictionary[@"email"];
    NSString *password   = dictionary[@"password"];

    NSLog(@"%@; %@; %@", identifier, email, password);
}
```

Comment: This is true, but the parse issue is the same once casted to NSArray, the indexes are still blank, I will post the parsing method soon

Comment: Why do u want to parse it again?

Comment: @DavidPullar I'm not sure what you mean by "the indexes are still blank". Nonetheless, I updated my answer to show how you now get the data out of the `responseObject` array.

Comment: Oh wow, the debugger had shown just a blank array when I tried view the contents as a `(NSDictionary *)responseObject[0]`. So assumed I couldn't access them. Thanks.